# Java regex replace all not replacing all words

Tags: java, regex

I've been playing with this regex in Java for ages and can't get it to work:

```
(?:^| )(?:the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)(?: |$)
```

The following:

```
pattern.matcher("the cat in the hat").replaceAll(" ")
```

gives me `cat the hat`. Another example input is `the cat in of the next hat` which gives me `cat of next hat`.

Is there any way I can make this regex replacement work without having to break them out into multiple separate regexes for each word and try to replace a string repeatedly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, you can do this pretty easily you just need to use [boundaries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which is what you're trying to describe with: `(?:^| )` Just do this instead:

```
\b(?:the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)\b
```

Your original didn't capture, but as is mentioned in the comments, if you want to capture the options you can use a capturing instead of a non-capturing group:

```
\b(the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)\b
```

Comment: You might also need match groups: `(\b(?:the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)\b)`

Comment: @frhd The best solution would then be to simply replace the non-capturing group by a capturing one: `\b(the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)\b`

Comment: @sp00m yep, this answer should be updated with your fix.

Comment: I don't need to know what was removed, so I can leave the capturing group out. It works, thanks, but I don't really understand why the original one doesn't work.

Comment: @frhd Well, it all depends on whether the OP needs to capture the data or not ;)

Comment: @RTF I hope that you saw [sp00m's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29678530/2642059). I didn't do a great job explaining *why* you should use boundaries, but that answer does explain  it very well.

Comment: @frhd The `\b` is an assertion (it doesn't match a character.) I can't seem to remember how this conversation played out over a year ago, but `\b(the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)\b` will result in the same capture as `(\b(?:the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)\b)`: [Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/xP4yT1/1)

Comment: @JonathanMee You're right, it's the same thing. I think back then I just expanded on your answer instead of getting rid of the non-matching assertion. I'm all for minimalism. +1 for revisiting.

Comment: @frhd Yeah I revisited because I was trying to find a good example for [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1681/regular-expressions/23701/anchors#t=201609261450110640553) to demonstrate `\b` and `\B`, but this is as close as I got :(

Answer (score 5):

The problem with yours is that the leading and trailing spaces are included in the matches, and a char cannot be found in two matches.

So with the input `the_cat_in_the_hat` (the underscores replace the spaces here, to make the explanation clearer):

1. First match: `the_`, remaining string: `cat_in_the_hat`
2. Second match: `_in_`, remaining string: `the_hat`
3. `the` is not matched, since it is neither preceded by a space nor by the beginning of the (original) string.

You could have used [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead, since they behave like conditions (i.e. `if`):

```
(?<=^| )(?:the|and|at|in|or|on|off|all|beside|under|over|next)(?= |$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ChKNoVEZkPje6yw7)

This way, you would have:

1. First match: `the`, remaining string: `_cat_in_the_hat`
2. Second match: `in`, remaining string: `_the_hat`
3. Third match: `the`, remaining string: `_hat`

But [@JonathanMee answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29678238/1225328) is the best solution, since word boundaries were implemented precisly for this purpose ;)

Comment: This is an excellent description of the problem, I prefer my final solution, but +1 because this makes a better answer.